# Not able to run Apache Hama examples

Tags: java, apache, hdfs, hama

I installed single node HDFS and local mode Apache Hama 0.7.1 and installations seemed to be successful.

But I am not able to test it by running any of the examples provided, like running PiEstimator:

```
$ $HAMA_HOME/bin/hama jar hama-examples-0.7.1.jar pi
18/04/04 01:47:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Except this warning, it doesn't output anything on terminal and nothing in `$HAMA_HOME/logs` directory as well and waits forever until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Most of the articles on the internet do not address this issue and it seems to run for everyone.

Pasting this if following is relevant (I'm very new to all this):

```
$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
2018-04-04 02:04:53,668 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Replicated Blocks:
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
Erasure Coded Block Groups: 
    Low redundancy block groups: 0
    Block groups with corrupt internal blocks: 0
    Missing block groups: 0
    Pending deletion blocks: 0
```